# How to create treelist click event in DevExpress?

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

My requirement is to develop a webpage where I have bind a treelist with database and based on user click on the treelist I have to show new textbox to add something to the Database. But using DevExpress I am unable to do that. Though I have found one sample answer from other forum which shows like below:

```
     private void treeList1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
     {
        DevExpress.XtraTreeList.TreeList tree = sender as DevExpress.XtraTreeList.TreeList;
        DevExpress.XtraTreeList.TreeListHitInfo info = tree.CalcHitInfo(tree.PointToClient(MousePosition));
       if (info.HitInfoType == DevExpress.XtraTreeList.HitInfoType.Cell)
       {

       }

     }
```

But when I try this on my asp.net project it can't find the XtraTreeList from the code behind and I am getting the following error:

```
 The type or namespace name 'XtraTreeList' does not exist in the namespace
 'DevExpress' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

Please help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you added reference to the dll of devexpress for TreeList?

Comment: XtraTreeList is a WinForms control. Looks like you need ASPxTreeList. BTW, why don't you contact DevExpress Support directly?